# PhoneGap Device ready not firing in ios but working fine in android emulator and ripple

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

Hey Guys I have a problem firing the deviceready on ios, but the code work just find on adnroid emulator and also ripple i dont know what could be the problem. i didnt try it on a readl android device but the emulator works fine, but i have tried it on iphone 5 which never call the device ready.i have another question also is it true that there is different js files for cordova for different platforms ?

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", deviceResume, false);

function deviceResume() {
doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded();
}

function deviceReady() {
deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}

$(document).one("mobileinit", function() {
jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();     
});

$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(
doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);

function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE] = 'No network connection';

if (networkState == Connection.NONE)
    alert('You have to be connected to the internet in order to use this app.');
else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("deals.html", {
            transition : "pop",
            reverse : false,
            changeHash : false
        });
    },1000);
}
}


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="controller/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jqueryMobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/handleHelpers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm.css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container splash" data-role="page" id="index">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would put your js in another file and add it with rest. Then call the function on body load <body onload="deviceReady()">.

Comment: it is already in another file which is index.js

Comment: Gald you got it working, sorry i thought the js code at the top was in the same page as it was not labeled so ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use phonegap along with jquery mobile, you need to use it like this,

```
$(document).one("mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();     
});
```

Comment: If have tried this but this not working, the problem is that the app never fire device ready

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the i had to delete the cordova js file from the directory and specify that on the config.xml for phonegap build . Thanks all

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "specify that on the config.xml"? I'm having the same problem, but I'm not sure what I could be doing.

Comment: You need to remove cordova js from the directory because phonegap build will add phonegap.js automatically on the build.